# Using SimpleDateFormat to format minutes to display in 2 digits

Tags: android, time, formatting

I am trying to make my countdown timer show the seconds as 2 digits instead of one.

Example: 02 instead of 2.

I am using the code below, but I am not having any luck with the formatting.

```
long  a = ((millisUntilFinished % 60000) / 1000);
String b = Long.toString(a);
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:");

String time = myFormat.format(b);
```

Comment: try `myFormat.format(new Date(a));`

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work but if possible try to have your a value in milliseconds. The below code is working fine for me.

```
long  a = 1395886625000L;
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String time = myFormat.format(a);
```